# Definition of algebraically closed field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

A field F is algebraically closed if every non constant polynomial in F[x] has a root in F.

Is this the right definition? I am wondering if only one root in F and the rest of the roots not in F can also be considered 'algebraically closed'?

I remember reading somewhere that if a root is in F then all roots are in F. Is this a special case of something? If so, could someone enlighten me on what it is?

Thank you

Comment: Only one root in $F$ and the rest of the roots not in $F$ can't be true for *all* polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every non-constant polynomial needs to have a root in the field; equivalently, it factors completely over the field.  The second statement is not saying the same thing, because if only one root $\alpha$ is in $\mathrm{F}$, then we can factor out $(x-\alpha)$ to obtain a new (non-constant) polynomial, which must also have a root in $\mathrm{F}$.

The third statement is maybe something you read about quadratics; certainly if one root of a quadratic over $\mathrm{F}$ is in $\mathrm{F}$, then the other root is as well.  But this statement is not true in general.

Answer (score 5):

1) The definition is right.

2) No. That not the same.

3) That's wrong. Consider $x(x^2+1)$ over the reals, which is not algebraically closed.